# Google packaged app - identity API - removeCachedAuthToken

Tags: google-chrome-app

**[google chrome 28]**
I am using `chrome.experimental.identity` API in a packaged app and getAuthToken works fine - get's token with which I can get user info, etc.
I understand that the identity API is moving out from being experimental to the trunk so as from chrome 29 I will be able to use `chrome.identity` and remove `"experimental"` permission from my manifest.

Q: If I want to make a logout button is `removeCachedAuthToken` the way to go about it? I tried to use it in the experimental.identity but it does nothing.

Answer (score 7):

To revoke token use this function from google sample app.

```js
function revokeToken() {
    user_info_div.innerHTML = "";
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: false }, 
      function (current_token) {
        if (!chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          // @corecode_begin removeAndRevokeAuthToken
          // @corecode_begin removeCachedAuthToken
          // Remove the local cached token
          chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({token: current_token}, function(){});
          // @corecode_end removeCachedAuthToken

          // Make a request to revoke token in the server
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open(
          "GET", 
          "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=" + current_token);
            
          xhr.send();
          // @corecode_end removeAndRevokeAuthToken

          // Update the user interface accordingly
          changeState(STATE_START);
          sampleSupport.log("Token revoked and removed from cache. " + 
            "Check chrome://identity-internals to confirm.");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No. It is not the way to go.

`removeCachedAuthToken` is a function that removes a token acquired using `getAuthToken` from the internal token cache. However, it does not revoke the token. That means that the application will no longer be able to access to the user resources in current session, until it calls `getAuthToken` again. When that happens, it will be able to obtain a token again without the user needing to grant access.

As such, this function is not meant to be a logout related routine. It is more of a recovery mechanism, when you realize that the access token that your application is using is stale, or invalid in any other way. That happens, when you make a request using the access token and the HTTP response status is 401 Unauthorized. In that case you can scrap the token and then request a new one using `getAuthToken`. To simulate that behavior, you can revoke the a relevant grant using the [Google Accounts page](https://accounts.google.com) or form the diagnostic UI: chrome://identity-internals (currently it lists all of the cached tokens).

Please refer to the [chrome app samples](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples) for GDocs and Identity. 
(Pull requests 114 for GDocs and 115 for Identity in case you are doing that in next few days.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is good to know. But I am still at the dark. How would I go about to revoke the token then?

Comment: thanks for pointing out the fact that removeCachedAuthToken does not revoke it actually.

Answer (score 1):

I too struggled with this but I eventually discovered this solution buried in the Chrome App Samples. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/gapi-chrome-apps-lib/gapi-chrome-apps.js

removeCachedAuthToken removes it locally, but to revoke the token from Google servers you needs to send a request, hence the second part: xhr.open('GET', 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' +
current_token);

Try this:

```js
function revokeToken() {
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: false }, 
      function (current_token) {
        if (!chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            // @corecode_begin removeAndRevokeAuthToken
            // @corecode_begin removeCachedAuthToken
            // Remove the local cached token
            chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({token: current_token}, function(){});
            // @corecode_end removeCachedAuthToken

            // Make a request to revoke token in the server
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=" + 
            current_token);
            xhr.send();
            // @corecode_end removeAndRevokeAuthToken

            // Update the user interface accordingly

            $("#revoke").get(0).disabled = true;
            console.log("Token revoked and removed from cache. " + 
              "Check chrome://identity-internals to confirm.");
        }
    });
}
```