# How to force the Google API/OAUTH consent screen?

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have a Chrome Extension that, in the manifest, includes the Drive API. On install, when the user opens a Google Doc, background.js pops the consent screen to get the user's permission to access their Google Drive.

This works fine on install. But if the user removes the app from Drive the code does NOT pop the consent screen again - it just gets a token and tries Drive only to get a 401 error.

I would have thought the auth call would pop consent if it isn't granted...

Obviously if a user removes your app you shouldn't keep asking for permission, necessarily - I'm just trying to deal with the simplest situation for now.

Some of my users never saw the consent page, or saw it and closed it...and are not prompted again.

**Manifest:**

```
"oauth2": {
        "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxx-smaehlat7c66p1ns6t90ssj3jmlrrecm.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
      ]
  },
```

**Background.js:**

```
googleFileID = getIdFromUrl(activeURL);

chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {

  console.log('In Chrome Identity and obtained token: ' + token);

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(request) {
      request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    },
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + googleFileID + "?fields=owners",
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: true,
    success: function(gDocsMeta1) {
      // DO STUFF
```

**Google API Console:**
I have set up the API and can see traffic, although 10% of my traffic is errors, which I attribute to the above problem.

I use Google Firebase for user authentication...if that is relevant. While some of my users opt for Google Authentication to create accounts, many use email signup. The problem afflicts both types of sign ups.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried removing the cached token with [`chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-removeCachedAuthToken) and then calling `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` again? On the other hand, 401 errors don't show up in Google API Console. I've found `drive.files.get` method to fail quite often. I now use `drive.files.list` with `q` parameter to filter the desired files

Comment: No, I hadn't. I got stuck in "revoke" as a way to accomplish this...So thank you.

I basically still had a token that wasn't good anymore...chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken seems to do the trick.

Here's a good discussion of the differences:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337107/google-packaged-app-identity-api-removecachedauthtoken

Many thanks! If you want to write this up as an answer I'd def accept it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you receive a 401 error as response, you have to remove the invalid token from cache using `chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({token:oldToken})` before calling `chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true} ...)` again.

Comment: Should you store that token somewhere other than javascript memory? How does it refresh (or does it)? If you just keep it in program memory, and it expires, does the user get the auth screen again?

Thank you!

Comment: You can keep it in Javascript memory. You have to refresh it manually: when you detect a 401 error, call `removeCachedAuthToken` to remove the expired token and then call `getAuthToken({interactive:true})` to get a fresh token. The auth screen will not be displayed again unless the user had revoked the permission.