# Switching YouTube user with OAuth2 shows previous user's data in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube, google-chrome-app, youtube-data-api, google-oauth

I have a Chrome Packaged App that uses oauth2 to authenticate to YouTube.  I'm using YouTube to determine the user's channel (via the channel endpoint).

It works for the first user authenticated.  But if I switch to a different user, the same YouTube call returns the previous user's data (i.e. channel).

Here are the steps I'm going through.

1. I get my auth token via a call to getAuthToken:
   `chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true, scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'] })`
2. I get their channel information.  I make a call to the channels endpoint like so:

   `` const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true';
   const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` };
   const config = {
   url,
   method: 'get',
   headers,
   responseType: 'json',
   };
   return axios(config); ``
3. This works!  The result of the call gives me the channel information.
4. The user removes their account.  I use the same sequence of calls that the Google Demo uses ([like this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21626506)):

   a. call `chrome.identiy.removeCachedAuthToken({ token })` with the token
   b. call `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=${token}` to revoke it
5. Everything is cleared out, I think.
   If I look at `chrome://identity-internals/` I still see the token, but the Token Status is set to `Not Found`

The issue:

1. I repeat from step 1, but I chose a different user.
2. I confirm that I get a new token that is different than the one I had previously
3. The call to the YouTube channels api returns the previous user's channel.

Comment: Are you sure that the previous owner's session was deleted? Try performing console.log to see which token is being used, etc.

Comment: Yes - I've been logging the token, and it is changing between users.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a caching issue with youtube.
I had to add `'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'` to my headers.

Here is the full headers line:

```
const headers = {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
};
```